# Grabbing correct variables for AJAX Post - from HTML/PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

In my `HTML`, I loop thru a `PHP` / `MySQL` query result and do something that makes `HTML` like this as the end result:

```
loop 1

<p>- user review-</p>
<a href=#" id="upvote">Up Vote</a>

loop 2

<p>- user review-</p>
<a href=#" id="upvote">Up Vote</a>

 etc.
```

Now, when the user clicks "up vote", I simply want an AJAX `POST` to send to a `PHP` script that looks like this:

```
// jQuery / AJAX - separate file linked to `HTML`

$('#upvote').onclick(function() {
        var user_id =  ??????;
        var review_id = ?????;
        $.ajax({
            url : "search_query.php",
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",  
            data : {
                userId : user_id,
                reviewId : review_id
            },
            success : function(data) {
                // do stuff
            }
});

// php

<?php
    $review_id = $database->escape_value(trim($_POST['reviewId']));
    $user_id= $database->escape_value(trim($_POST['userId']));

    // Upvote Method
    $result = Data::upVoteReview($review_id, $user_id);

    // Not discussed in question  
    $output["result"] = $result;
    print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

My question is: I need to grab two variables from `HTML` and put in the AJAX `POST`;  as you see above, they are `reviewId` and `userId`.  (Note the `user_id` is the logged in user and is actually stored as a global `PHP` `SESSION` variable.)

The difficult part is the HTML is dynamic, and each loop will have a different review_id.  The user_id will be the same but I am not sure how to get that from a `SESSION` var to the JavaScript.  Note:  In each "loop" on the `HTML` page I do have access to the `review_id` php variable that I need - just not sure where to place it so I can pick it up in `jQuery`/`AJAX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes instead of IDs as propper markup there should be only 1 ID of a given name per page.

HTML

```
loop 1

<p>- user review-</p>
<a href="#" class="upvote" data-review="1">Up Vote</a>

loop 2

<p>- user review-</p>
<a href="#" class="upvote" data-review="2">Up Vote</a>

 etc.
```

JS

```
// jQuery / AJAX - separate file linked to `HTML`

$('.upvote').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var review_id = this.data('review');
        $.ajax({
            url : "search_query.php",
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",  
            data : {
                reviewId : review_id
            },
            success : function(data) {
                // do stuff
            }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $review_id = $database->escape_value(trim($_POST['reviewId']));

  // Upvote Method
    $result = Data::upVoteReview($review_id, $_SESSION['user_id']);

    $output["result"] = $result;
    print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant on the `user_id` solution - so simple.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be quite a few problems in your code, the first couple of ones I've noticed are the following:

The first one:

```
loop 1

<p>- user review-</p>
<a href=#" id="upvote">Up Vote</a> <------------------------------Here

loop 2

<p>- user review-</p>
<a href=#" id="upvote">Up Vote</a> <-------------------------------Here

 etc.
```

You are missing the opening quotes, i.e. it should be `href="#"` not `href=#"`

Second is:

```
$('#upvote').onclick(function() {
```

should probably be as jQuery does not have `onclick` function, it definitely has `on` function.

```
$('#upvote').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: First one was a typo.  Second one, I hadn't got to that part yet but I do thank you for that tidbit.  I'm used to using regular JavaScript.

Comment: @KickingLettuce, it happens.  Have you solved your problem yet?